While sending the Email campaign from Sitecore EXM, the user got the mail,but unable to get unique link page individually
when you try to send email campaign mail to different recipient, there is a unique link present in email template for each individual. but when the user wants to open it , rather than opening their unique page, they can able to check the other recipient address and information in their unique pages that is not what they suppose to see instead of seeing their information.
ex: suppose a user wants to see their email and information  while open the unique link page, but he can see other person (b) information.
May i know what may cause this issue?


Can you elaborate a bit more? And maybe attach some screenshots?

Is your EXM component that outputs Email address cached by any chance? Where do you get the email address from?

@AnnaGevel i have uploaded the contact list in listmanager., and in the contact list i have added the user name, email ids and phone number, from there i have added the the recipient list while send the campaign mail. and it is not cached actually

@smrutisatapathy Sorry, I meant in the code of the component that outputs "What posts do you want" and pre-populated email address, where does it take the email address from?
